# How can I work with vector image in Android?

Tags: android, dictionary

I'm an amateur in working with vectors, bitmap and Images in generally.
I want to create an App that it contains map section. Also, I want to tag on map

Now, I have some questions, please help me:

1. Which one is best? Using `bitmap` or `vector`
2. If I should use vector, what should I use image format? SVG?
3. what the best way for Implementation?

If you have an other suggestions to me, please write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Parse SVG files on the go by using this library, very simple and efficient to use.

http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/

Comment: I've get it. what your suggestion? Do you mean I should use it to processing pictures?

Comment: Yes! Save the svgs in ur assets folder and render it at runtime

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in google maps to create rich, beautiful map apps. No need to implement your own maps and graphics. You can embed tags and stuff too.

Check out:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview

Comment: Thanks @Anup, but I have to implement it an other way. because I have different images. you know?

Comment: I believe you can use your own images for your tags, if that is what you are after.

Comment: Do you mean I can use my images with Google map API?

Comment: I think so. Go through the guide above once.